# como chama uma função do javascript em todos botoes com uma classe

Tags: javascript, html

gostaria de chama essa função que ta chamado todos as imput por `id="inviardesb"` e troca-las por todos input que tenha `<div class="classchama">`

como eu chamo por div essa função

```
<div class="buttons">
<div class="classchama">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Cadastrar produto" id="inviardesb">
</div>
</div>  

Live.disableDataSubmit = function() {
    $("#inviardesb").on('click', function (event) {  
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
}
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais especifico?

Comment: Acho que voce quer que todos os botoes de uma determinada classe ao clicar em qualquer um deles chame uma funcao, e isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso basta trocar o seletor, segue abaixo:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="classchama">
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Cadastrar produto" id="inviardesb">
    </div>
</div>  

Live.disableDataSubmit = function() {
    $("div.classchama input").on('click', function (event) {  
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    });
}
```

O novo seletor é `div.classchama input` que detalhado:

> Seleciona todas as tags `div` que contenha a classe `classchama` e em seguida procura dos descendentes que sejam uma tag `input`

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, apenas troque o #inviardesb para .inviardesb:

```
Live.disableDataSubmit = function() {
$(".inviardesb input").on('click', function (event) {  
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```